# Water and Atmospheric Conditions in Earth prehistory

Tags: earth-history, climate-models, atmosphere-modelling, atmospheric-chemistry, precambrian

I pose this question as a curious enthusiast lacking formal education in chemistry or Earth sciences. My intrigue has been kindled by various articles and discussions and while I may not be certain of the words needed to convey this, I'm hopeful that you can guide me in the right direction.

My curiosity is about theories around Earth's early prehistoric atmosphere and the conditions that might have facilitated the existence of vast quantities of water in an as of yet unknown gaseous or vapor state.

What types of gases and atmospheric pressures would have been requisite to maintain a substantial amount of water in the atmosphere? What specific hypothetical Earth states or conditions would be necessary to sustain it?

Conversely what shifts or processes might lead to the consolidation of this "state" into downpours or bodies of liquid water and oceans?

I have encountered theories suggesting that Earth's water oceans did not exist in a distant prehistory. And that the early Earth's atmosphere may have been rich in greenhouse gases like CO2 and CH4, contributing to higher temperatures and pressures than those we are familiar with today. Your guidance and insights would be appreciated. Because these questions have bothered me for a while.